# Boost Python Example: cannot find "-lboost_python"

Tags: c++, ubuntu, boost, boost-python

I was following a [starter example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31391400/can-python-c-extension-get-a-c-object-and-call-its-member-function) on how to access a C++ class from Python using boost. (I'm currently working on Ubuntu 21.) I created the file `foo.cpp`:

```cpp
// foo.cpp
#include <boost/python.hpp>

class A {

 public:

  A(int i)
      : m_i{i} { }

  int get_i() const {
    return m_i;
  }
 private:
  // don't use names such as `_i`; those are reserved for the
  // implementation
  int m_i;
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(foo) {
  using namespace boost::python;

  class_<A>("A", init<int>())
      .def("get_i", &A::get_i, "This is the docstring for A::get_i")
      ;
}
```

I then compiled with the command (I'm using Python 3.9 on my system):

```
g++ -o foo.so foo.cpp -std=c++11 -fPIC -shared \
-Wall -Wextra `python3.9-config --includes --libs` \
-lboost_python
```

However, the compile fails with:

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/sp_thread_sleep.hpp:22,
                 from /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/yield_k.hpp:23,
                 from /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/spinlock_gcc_atomic.hpp:14,
                 from /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/spinlock.hpp:42,
                 from /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/spinlock_pool.hpp:25,
                 from /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:29,
                 from /usr/include/boost/shared_ptr.hpp:17,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python/converter/shared_ptr_to_python.hpp:12,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python/converter/arg_to_python.hpp:15,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python/call.hpp:15,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python/object_core.hpp:14,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python/args.hpp:22,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python.hpp:11,
                 from foo.cpp:2:
/usr/include/boost/bind.hpp:36:1: note: ‘#pragma message: The practice of declaring the Bind placeholders (_1, _2, ...) in the global namespace is deprecated. Please use <boost/bind/bind.hpp> + using namespace boost::placeholders, or define BOOST_BIND_GLOBAL_PLACEHOLDERS to retain the current behavior.’
   36 | BOOST_PRAGMA_MESSAGE(
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/boost/detail/iterator.hpp:13:1: note: ‘#pragma message: This header is deprecated. Use <iterator> instead.’
   13 | BOOST_HEADER_DEPRECATED("<iterator>")
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_python
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

There are some notes there, but the error seems to be from the inability to find `-lboost_python` (or `-lboost_python3`).

I used [a guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147474/how-can-i-find-boost-version) to check if boost is installed on my system and it is. I then read [a guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55578394/how-to-fix-usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lboost-python) about finding `-lboost_python` which told me to try and make a symbolic link between `libboost_python.so` and the shared library in `/usr/lib/`. I checked `/usr/lib` and found `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python39.so` and tried to make a symbolic link with:

```
sudo ln -s libboost_python39.so libboost_python.so
```

but get the error message that:

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link 'libboost_python.so': File exists
```

Which I assume means that the appropriate link already exists (but I'm not sure).

I've been looking around trying to find more guidance on what to do, but I'm stuck now. Does anyone have any insight has to why my system can't find `-lboost_python`? Also does anyone know if the notes that were thrown during my attempt to compile are issues that need to be corrected, or are they just warnings?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: have you installed the boost python development package (`libboost-python-dev`)?

Comment: It is probably called libboost_python39 (but check on your system).

Comment: @AlanBirtles Indeed I already had ```libboost-python-dev``` installed.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Do you mean trying it with the flag ```-libboost_python39```? I tried that and ```-libboost_python``` but those didn't work.

Comment: No, I didn't mean that. What I did mean is the actual file name of the library should be something like libboost_python39.so. Your flag then would have to be `-lboost_python39`.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Thanks for the clarification! That did it!